# Manually escape a string for raw SQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a raw SQL statement to be executed using SqlAlchemy. The query contains this:

```
FROM unnest(array['sku1', 'sku2', 'sku3'])
```

Building the query manually, I could not find a way to escape each parameter manually.

I tried doing:

```
session.execute("... FROM unnest(array[:skus]) ...", {'skus': skus})
```

but:

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 21:         FROM unnest(array[('sku1', 'sku2', '...
                      ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Python `tuple` is adapted to a Postgresql `record` and a `list` adapted to an `array`. That is why in this case a tuple is not valid.

But what you say [in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25617630/131874) that works does not:

```
select unnest(['BA007EWCBD43', "KA036'AGHF550", 'KA036ACBK873']);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: select unnest(['BA007EWCBD43', "KA036'AGHF550", 'KA036ACBK87...
```

Or you mean

```
FROM unnest(ARRAY['BA007EWCBD43', "KA036'AGHF550", 'KA036ACBK873'])
```

The parameters should never be manually escaped. Let it to the driver.

Comment: yes, you're right. that's because I had a custom logger that printed this. Do you know a method to see the real query that goes to the SQL server instead of `... FROM unnest(%(skus)s) ... INFO 2014-09-02 15:21:10,419 sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'skus': ['IN002EWKU161', 'FA003BMAYD09', "NI464E'WFA620", 'NI464EWCI491']}`? But not using server logs?

Comment: @warvariuc I don't know how to get the final sql query other than reading the server log. But the sqlalchemy people sure know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I put a `list` of skus (not a `tuple`), everything is fine:

```
session.execute("... FROM unnest(:skus) ...", {'skus': ['BA007EWCBD43', 'KA036\'AGHF550', 'KA036ACBK873']})
```

Which generates:

```
FROM unnest(['BA007EWCBD43', "KA036'AGHF550", 'KA036ACBK873'])
```

Though a function to manually quote parameters would is still needed for other cases.